# Riemann-Hilbert correspondence versus Simpson correspondence

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let us assume that $X$ is a connected, smooth complex algebraic variety. Then the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence tells us that the functor which sends a flat connection with regular singularities on a vector bundle of $X$ to its asocciated monodromy representation is an equivalence of categories.

Furthermore, the Simpson correspondence tells us that there is an equivalence of categories between the category of complex representations of the fundamental group of curves and the category of semi-stable Higgs bundles with trivial Chern class.

Its seems to me that the Simpson correspondence should be a consequence of the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, especially since the category of Higgs bundles is roughly the tangent category of the category of vector bundles. However, based on the number of papers written on this, and the fact that Simpson wrote a ICM note on this, this is clearly not the case. So I guess I must miss what the additional content of the Simpson correspondence is. Could someone help me?

Comment: Isn't the Simpson correspondence about unitary representations only? Also, does the Simpson correspondence go through the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, or is it a different functor?

Comment: "It seems to me" does not seem to be based on anything and is actually wrong. My suggestion is to read Hitchin's paper first: It deals with Riemann surfaces and is easier to read (still quite hard though).  The relation opers-flat connections-Higgs bundles is very tricky even in the Riemann surface case and was the subject of Giaotto's conjecture, solved in "Opers versus nonabelian Hodge" by Dumitrescu et al.

Comment: This was crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355687/riemann-hilbert-correspondence-versus-simpson-correspondence